# Rapidminer more than one query text analysis

Tags: twitter, sentiment-analysis, rapidminer

I am using `rapidminer` because I want to perform a sentiment analysis. 
The things are, I have 7 queries that I need to analyze together (companies' names that I need to analyze to obtain insights about the customer).
So my idea was then to extract the data with twitter app developer and then put in `rapidminer` to analyze.

1. When I open this data in `rapidminer` it shows that
   there are some problems with the dataset with the following:

   ```
   Error: file syntax error
   Message: Value quotes not closed at position 346.
   Last characters read: ght.
   Help enter code here
   ```

   **-How do I fix this?**
2. Once enter my spreadsheet data (.csv file). It shows me the error"
   [Cause: Unparseable number: "FALSE"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaBmI.png)
   I've searched here already for answers but none helped me to solve this error.
3. Is it possible to analyze this data altogether or do I
   have to do it separately?
   I'm not sure if this is feasible, I
   suppose it would interfere in the overall analysis?

I'm quite new at `rapidminer`, so I appreciate you all's help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the file around position 346?

Comment: Yes I did, but there are many others with the same error, but I don't know how to fix it. Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

I decided to ignore the problem so I just selected the option to replace errors with missing values. And analyze all data together.